# Dynamic generate shortcode for my form builder

Tags: php, wordpress, shortcode, wordpress-shortcode

I am developing a form builder plugin to drag and build forms and i have developed to the point where i can build a form. Now my issue is when i click save form it should generate a shortcode and save in the database which can be used to call the form on the front end. Below is what i have done which generates shortcode but does not  display anything on front end

```
  //build form shortcode

  function formbuilder_ajax_call(){

  $form_content = trim($_POST['form_content']);
  $email = trim($_POST['email']);
  $other_email = trim($_POST['other_email']);
  $subject = trim($_POST['subject']);
  $sender = trim($_POST['sender']);
  $message = trim($_POST['message']);
  $form_name = trim($_POST['form_name']);

  $form_array = array(); 

  $form_array = array(

  "form_content" => $form_content,   //html form content to use to build form
  "email" => $email,
  "other_email" => $other_email,
  "subject" => $subject,
  "sender" => $sender,
  "message" => $message,
  "form_name" => $form_name,

   );  

   return  $form_array;
   }

 function shortcode_form(){

$get_info = formbuilder_ajax_call();
$form_name = $get_info['form_name'];
$email = $get_info['email'];

$subject = $get_info['subject'];

$sender = $get_info['sender'];

$message = $get_info['message'];

$other_email = $get_info['other_email'];


echo $get_info['form_content'];


}


function form_mail() {

$get_mailinfo = formbuilder_ajax_call();

if ( isset( $_POST['submit'] ) ) {
    
      // sanitize form values
    $name    = sanitize_text_field( $_POST["field1"] );
    $email   = sanitize_email( $_POST["field3"] );
    $subject =  sanitize_text_field($_POST["field4"]);
    $message    = sanitize_text_field( $_POST["field5"] );
    $to = $get_mailinfo['email'];
    $subject = $get_mailinfo['subject'];
    $body = "Name: $name \n\nEmail: $email \n\nSubject: $subject \n\nMessage: $message";
    $headers = 'From: '.$name.' <'.$to.'>' . "\r\n" . 'Reply-To: ' . $email;
    
    wp_mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers);

}
}

function get_shortcode() {
ob_start();

shortcode_form();
form_mail(); 

return ob_get_clean();
}


  
function make_short_code() { 

global $wpdb;

$table_name = $wpdb->prefix . 'contactform';

$get_mailinfo = formbuilder_ajax_call();

$var_shortcode = 'display_form_'.rand();

$function_shortcode = get_shortcode();

add_shortcode( $var_shortcode, $function_shortcode );

$wpdb->insert( $table_name, array(
 'Name' => $get_mailinfo['form_name'],
 'shortcode' => $var_shortcode,
 'email' => $get_mailinfo['email'],
 'other_email' => $get_mailinfo['other_email'],
 'subject' => $get_mailinfo['subject'],
 'sender' => $get_mailinfo['sender'],
 'form_content' => $get_mailinfo['form_content'],
 'message' => $get_mailinfo['message']
 ) );

var_dump($get_mailinfo);

}

Javascript to submit form without loading 

       jQuery("#button_to_load_data").click(function() {
         var email = $("#email").val();
       var other_email = $("#other_email").val();
       var subject = $("#subject").val();
       var sender = $("#sender").val();
       var message = $("#message").val();
       var form_name = $("#form_name").val();
       var content = getPlainHtml();
 //    alert(content);
        var data = {
        'action'   : 'make_short_code', // the name of your PHP function!
        'form_content' : content,           // another random value we'd like to pass
        'email' : email,
        'other_email' : other_email,
        'subject' : subject,
        'sender' : sender,
        'message' : message,
        'form_name' : form_name,
        
        };
        
        
       
   
     jQuery.post(ajaxurl, data, function(response) {
        jQuery("#receiving_div_id").html(response);
     });
  

  });
```

I use var_dump function as a means to track that the form html content is being carried from the form builder to my functions to make the shortcode. But the shortcode does not work. The shortcode is saved in the database so that end users can see it on a table where they can copy and use on their front end.

shortcode table:

[image]

Formbuilder

[image]

[image]

Comment: It looks like you are only calling `add_shortcode` once, at the time you make your database insert. That is not how shortcodes work, this needs to be executed _every time_ the page loads.

Comment: @CBroe, in that case how do i call it each time  a page loads.